# Exploring the isomorphisms of the group algebra $KG$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, solution-verification, group-rings, ring-isomorphism

Let $G=\langle \sigma \rangle $ be a cyclic group of order $3$ (or if you prefer $G=C_3$) .

1. We would like to prove that $\Bbb C G$ is a direct sum of fields.
2. We would like to prove that $\Bbb Q G$ is also a direct sum of fields.
3. If $K$ is a field of characteristic $3$, we would like to prove that 
   $$KG \cong K[X]/\langle X^3 \rangle,$$
   as rings.

*Proof.* 1. We define the map 
$\theta: \Bbb C[X] \longrightarrow \Bbb C G,\ f(X) \longmapsto \theta (f(X)):= f(\sigma).$
Then, this is a ring homomorphism with image $\mathrm{Im} \theta= \Bbb C G$, so $\theta$ is in fact a surjective homomorphism. We now claim that $\mathrm{Ker} \theta = \langle X^3-1 \rangle$. For the $\supseteq$, we have $$\theta(X^3-1)= \sigma ^3 -1 =0 \implies X^3-1 \in \mathrm{Ker} \theta \implies \langle X^3-1\rangle \subseteq \mathrm{Ker} \theta.$$

For the $\subseteq$, take $f(X)\in \mathrm{Ker} \theta$. Then, by the Division Algorithm we have 
$$f(X)=q(X)(X^3-1)+r(X),\ \text{ where } r(X)=0 \text{ or } \deg r(X) \leq 2.$$
Then, $0=\theta (f(X))=\theta(r(X)) \iff r(\sigma)=0 \iff a\sigma^2+b\sigma+1=0 \iff a=b=0$, where $a,b\in \Bbb C$ So, $r(X)=0$ and $\mathrm{Ker} \theta \subseteq \langle X^3-1 \rangle$. Finally, we obtain the equality. So, by the 1st Iso Theorem for rings, we have 
$$\Bbb C C_3 \cong \Bbb C[X]/ \langle X^3-1 \rangle.$$
Since $X^3-1=(X-1)(X^2+X+1)=(X-1)(X-\alpha)(X-\alpha^2)$, be the Chinese Remainder Theorem, we have 
$$\Bbb C C_3 \cong \Bbb C[X]/ \langle X^3-1 \rangle \cong \Bbb C[X]/\langle X-1 \rangle \times \Bbb C[X]/\langle X-\alpha \rangle \times \Bbb C[X]/\langle X-\alpha^2\rangle,$$
and we are done.

2. Following the same technique, since $X^3-1=(X-1)(X^2+X+1)$ is the factorisation into irreducibles, we obtain
   $$\Bbb Q C_3 \cong \Bbb Q[X]/ \langle X^3-1 \rangle \cong \Bbb Q[X]/\langle X-1 \rangle \times \Bbb Q[X]/\langle X^2+X+1 \rangle,$$
   and we are done.

**Questions.**

1) Are the proofs of 1. and 2. complete and correct?

2) How do we cope with 3. ?

*Thank you.*

Comment: 1 and 2 look complete and correct to me. 3 is the same idea. $KG \simeq K[x]/(x^3-1)$. The trick now is to notice that when $\operatorname{char} K =3$, $x^3-1$ factors as $(x-1)^3$. Then there is an automorphism of $K[x]$ carrying $x-1$ to $x$, and you're done.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Could you please elaborate on your last sentence?

Comment: Sure, I mean that homomorphisms of polynomial rings are defined by where you send $x$, so if you send $x$ to $x+1$, you send $x-1$ to $x$. This induces an isomorphism between the quotient rings, $K[x]/((x-1)^3)$, and $ K[x]/(x^3)$.

Comment: In other words, we have 
$$\eta: K[X]/\langle (X-1)^3 \rangle  \longrightarrow K[X]/\langle X^3 \rangle,\\ f(X)+ \langle (X-1)^3 \rangle \longmapsto f(X+1)+ \langle X^3 \rangle.$$
Am I right?

Also, I have another idea: Let's define my $\theta$ as
$$\theta: \Bbb C[X] \longrightarrow \Bbb C G,\\ f(X) \longmapsto \theta (f(X)):= f(1-\sigma).$$
I think it works! What do you say?

Comment: @Christ Yes, both of those sound correct to me.

Comment: @jgog Many thanks! If you write an answer, I ll accept it :)